# Prove that $\omega(v,u)=0$ $\forall u \in \mathbb R^m$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

if $\omega:\mathbb R^m\times \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$ one alternant 2-tensor. Prove that if $m$ is odd then exist $v\in \mathbb R^m$ such that $\omega(v,u)=0$ $\forall u\in \mathbb R^m$.
I dont have idea how to start just use the definition,hence $\omega$ is alternant 2-tensor then $\omega(x,y)=-\omega(y,x)$.

So, for example $\omega(x,x)=0\quad\forall x\in \mathbb R^m$, if i suppose that exist $\tilde{v}$ then
$\omega(\tilde{v},u)=\omega(\tilde{v},u)+\omega(u,u)$ imply $\omega(\tilde{v}+u,u)=\omega(\tilde{v},u)=-\omega(u,\tilde{v})$. But what can i do with all equalitys, how to use that $\mathbb R^m$ where $m$ is odd, somebody can help me please, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent $\omega$ as the $m\times m$ matrix $\omega_{ij} = \omega (e_i, e_j)$, where $\{e_1, \cdots, e_m\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\omega_{ij} = -\omega_{ji}$ since $\omega$ is skew-symmetric. Thus the matrix $W = (w_{ij})$ satisfies $W^t = -W$. Then

$$\det W = \det W^t = \det (-W) = (-1)^m \det W = -\det W$$
since $m$ is odd. Thus $\det W = 0$ and there is a nontrivial vector $v =(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n)$ so that $Wv=0$. This means

$$ \omega (v, u) = 0$$
for all $u\in \mathbb R^m$.

Comment: excusme, are you using converse of:  $Ax=0$ for $x\neq 0$ iff $Det A\neq 0$? can you help me please, im confuse